# provider shared memory provider error 40 could not open a connection visual studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have no idea what happened... I am working for fun on a little project. I realized a database inside Visual Studio 2010 and then I was able to see the tables, make queries and all the other fun things. Today after dinner (ok food wasn't great but I guess is not relevant...) I opened the project and I got an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error:40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My connection string is:

```
<add name="connection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

What happened? Can be something changed inside IIS7.5? Is sql a foodie and noticed the bad food?

Thanks to all of you!

Dan

Answer (score 5):

If your connection is localhost, it may be that you need to re-register  servers.  Also, it may be that certain Server services have stopped.  You can restart SQL Server services for any Server using SQL Server Configuration Manager.  You can do this easily from SQL Server Management Studio.

Here are the specifics:
Start Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio by searching for it in Windows All Apps (Win10) - listed under Microsoft SQL Server. Once launched, go to **View Menu** select **Registered Servers**. In the Registered Servers window, appears **Local Server Groups**.  4 Icons show at top of pane: Database, Analysis, Reporting, Integration.  Make sure Database is clicked.  Click **Local Server Groups**.

Your server may already be listed, but I find it useful to re-register all local servers:  Right-click on **Local Server Groups**, hover over **Tasks**, and select **Register Local Servers**.  This process registers all possible local servers at once.  Each server appears as is either red/stopped or blue/paused or green/running.  Right-click a server, select **Service Control** and choose available stop/pause/run.

It may be helpful to run **SQL Server Configuration Manager** to view/change all SQL Server services.  To do so, right-click any Server and select **Server Configuration Manager...**.  This launches **Sql Server Configuration Manager** (after User account request to allow this to change Windows, click Yes to Run).  If **SQL Server Services** is selected on the left pane, a full list of SQL Server Services appears in the right pane. Right-click on a SQL Server Service in the right pane will provide you with the same options above: stop/pause/run.

This information and much more can be accessed in at [Tutorial: SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms170681.aspx), which I found quite helpful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar error in 2014.

I have a nasty habit of leaving my machine on over night which seems to play some role in initiating the problem.

The solution that works for me in the 2014 edition is to:

-Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  This appears to be a separate utility in the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 folder.

-Once the app opens right click on SQL Server (x) instance.  Where x = your server instance name.

After starting you should be able to re access you database.  You can close the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

If you don't have SQL Server 2014 it is fairly straight forward to install and you should be able to use your old code through the studio.  Setting up your database may be another story.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I resolved this issue.

Step 1. Make sure SQL SERVER is up and the instance you try to connect is running.

Step 2. Your system Firewall should not block SQL Server port.

Step 3. Go to Computer Management >> Service and Application >> SQL Server 2005 Configuration >> Network Configuration: Enable TCP/IP protocol. Make sure that SQL SERVER port is by Default 1433.